# Angular ngModel select in ie11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, ngmodel

I have a form with 2 select:
[image]
But in IE11 options are not displayed:
[image]
I use ng Model in select, without it everything is displayed perfectly, what could be the reason?

Comment: Is this the same issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6703?

Comment: @KevinZhang, adding the es6-shim didn't help

Comment: There is a workaround mentioned in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6573 `<select [ngModel]="value" (change)="changeValue($event.target.value)">`, try with it.

Comment: @KevinZhang, any mention of ngModel breaks ie11)

Comment: Please add the source parts of the template and the component that are relevant.

Comment: @KevinZhang, in the end, I gave up ngModel, thanks for the help this example helped ($event.target.value)

Comment: Which version of Angular version are you using? Without any of the code, it is hard to narrow down the problem, so, I suggest you could post enough code or create  a stackblitz example to reproduce the problem. Here is a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7kzu8w?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) about using angular ngModel and select tag, you could refer to it. Besides, you could also use F12 developer tools to check if there have any error in the Console tool.